# Python create instance attributes by kwargs

Tags: python, class, attributes

Need help with a little problem here. I want to create instance attributes from the input to a class `__init__` method.

```py
class Test():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Create instance attributes from dict"""


t = Test(a=1, b=2, c=3)

print(t.a, t.b, t.c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kwargs` is a dictionary and you can set class attributes from a dictionary using `self.__dict__`:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

t = Test(a=1, b=2, c=3)
print(t.a, t.b, t.c)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `self.__setattr__()`:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            self.__setattr__(key, val)


t = Test(a=1, b=2, c=3)

print(t.a, t.b, t.c)
# 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `kwargs` and set attributes by calling `setattr()`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Create instance attributes from dict"""
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

```
t = Test(a=1, b=2, c=3)

print(t.a, t.b, t.c)
```

Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_setattr.asp) for more details about `setattr()` method in Python.

Check [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs) for more details about Python **kwargs.

Answer (score 1):

The `setattr` function is the friend you're looking for:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, v)

t = Test(1, b=2, c=3)

print(t.a, t.b, t.c)
```

Result:

```
1 2 3
```

In more complex code, you might not want to assign all of the key/value pairs in **kwargs as instance attributes, and you might want to be sure that the caller provides some required values.  You could make the params explicit and still get the behavior you want, with something like:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__setattr__('a', a)
        self.__setattr__('b', b)
        if 'c' in kwargs:
            self.__setattr__('c', kwargs['c'])

t = Test(1, 2, c=3)

print(t.a, t.b, t.c)
```

Same result:

```
1 2 3
```

Answer (score -2):

I'll fill in what you're missing here:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Create instance attributes from dict"""
        self.a = kwargs["a"]
        self.b = kwargs["b"]
        self.c = kwargs["c"]

t = Test(a=1, b=2, c=3)
print(t.a, t.b, t.c)
```

Comment: You have completely misunderstood the meaning of the question. OP needs to accept any keyword parameter and set the attribute with the same name according to the keyword.